# Массив не записывается в txt

Tags: c#

Вот код,есть три TextBox,в них вводятся значения и Button1 сохраняет массив в txt.На деле файл создается,пустой

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static string n1;
    public static string n2;
    public static string n3;
    public static string[] massiv = { n1, n2, n3 };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\Users\\D\\Documents\\Massiv.txt", massiv);

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n1 = textBox1.Text.ToString();
    }
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n2 = textBox2.Text.ToString();
    }
    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n3 = textBox4.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: вот здесь `public static string[] massiv = { n1, n2, n3 };` ты добавил пустые строки...... при `TextChanged` не происходит автоматичекой замены значений в массиве, всё что ты изменяешь, это значения в `n1`,`n2` и `n3`

Answer (score 1):

В момент создания массива

```
public static string[] massiv = { n1, n2, n3 };
```

переменные `n1, n2, n3` имеют значение `null`. Их последующее присваивание никак на элементы массива не влияет из-за immutability типа `string`.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string

Comment: `null`? а я думал по дефолту они пустой строкой инициализированы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, `string` - ссылочный тип, дефолтное значение - `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Переменные n1, n2, n3 располагаются совсем в другом месте памяти после их очередной инициализации. Массив massiv хранит старые адреса переменных, которые могут быть к моменту использования массива изменены.
Если сильно не менять структуру программы, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
public static string n1;
public static string n2;
public static string n3;
public static string[] massiv = { n1, n2, n3 };

private static void CreateArray()
{
    //Инициализируем массив при необходимости
    massiv = new string[]{ n1, n2, n3 };
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CreateArray();
  System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\Users\\D\\Documents\\Massiv.txt", massiv);
}
```

Comment: А если сильно менять структуру?

Comment: На самом деле, все зависит от ситуации. Думаю, что насчет структуры я погорячился) В зависимости от задачи Вашей программы можно было бы ввести методы проверки вводимых строк. В случае простых правил проверки можно представить поля n1, n2, n3 как свойства и в них определить правила проверки.